# Drupal CSS, images etc not loading

Tags: css, .htaccess, drupal

We took on a new client with a Drupal site. I'm trying to migrate the site to one of our servers. The site is loading but none of the CSS, images, etc are (looks like most of them are in sites/default/files).

I've verified the files are there, but they're sending back 403 (Forbidden). I verified permissions and owners are correct. In the Drupal .htaccess files it has an odd line:

```
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
```

This appears to be blocking direct access to those files. I've tried to research this but haven't found anything useful. I'm assuming there's some way Drupal reroutes requests to those files somehow, but that's where I'm stuck.

Anyone know what might be going on here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the lines below:

> SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
>
> Options None
>
> Options +FollowSymLinks

for this ones:

> SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
>
> Options None
>
> **Options +SymLinksifOwnerMatch**

Which Drupal version do you have instaled?